# File.canRead() returns false

Tags: java, linux, file

I have a server client program, with server running on Raspberry Pi (running Linux) and client being a Android application. I am writing a in application file browser, which simply sends a path to the server and in turn server returns the list of files using `file.listFiles()` (server is written in Java).

I run the server / Java program as `sudo`, hoping that this would give access to all the files across system, but to my surprise, this user does not have read permissions on `/home` directory of Pi.

So here is what happens in sequence:

I request `file.listFiles(new File("/"));` which is sent over socket from Pi to Android app. In the app, before making the next request, I check if I can read the file using `file.canRead();` and for `/home` directory, this returns false.

File permissions on Pi:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ls -l / | grep home
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Dec 31  1969 home
```

How I run my Java server:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo java -cp "/usr/local/lib/bluecovelib/bluecove/target/bluecove-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/usr/local/lib/bluecovelib/bluecove-gpl-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT/target/bluecove-gpl-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/pi/severinteractionutils.jar:." AppConnect
```

Why does `sudo` user does not have access to `/home` directory from the Java program?

EDIT:

I ran a simple program on Pi to test if it is because the underlying OS has changed. Apparently it does have an effect.

```
public class TestFileBrowser {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
        File file = new File("/");
        File [] files = file.listFiles();
        for(int i=0; i<files.length; ++i) {
            if(files[i].getAbsolutePath().equals("/home")) {
                File homeDir = files[i];
                if(homeDir.canRead()) {
                    System.out.println("Can Read");
                    if (homeDir.isDirectory()) {
                        System.out.println("Is directory");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the console snapshot:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo javac TestFileBrowser.java 
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo java TestFileBrowser
Hello, World
Can Read
Is directory
```

Answer (score 2):

> and for /home directory, this returns false.

Correct, because you can't read from a directory using typical File Stream IO. You can call [`File.isDirectory()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29) which (per the Javadoc)

> Tests whether the file denoted by this abstract pathname is a directory.
>
> *Where it is required to distinguish an I/O exception from the case that the file is not a directory, or where several attributes of the same file are required at the same time, then the [`Files.readAttributes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAttributes(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...)) method may be used.*

And you can check permission to read with the attributes.

Comment: So, how can I  get the contents of the `/home` directory in this case. Basically, how to get a functional remote file browser. Also, `file.isDirectory()` returns false for me.

Comment: Then you can't get the contents because it isn't a directory. Try something like `new File(System.getProperty("user.home")).listFiles();`

Comment: I tried that, but since I was running the program as sudo (which is needed due to other things in the program) it returned `/root` as the home directory which isn't useful. Also,  please see the content of `ls -l / | grep home` in question, which states that it is a directory

Comment: Doesn't mean that a non-root user would have a "/home" directory (and running as sudo means you could read any directory that exists).

Comment: Yeah. That's what it should be. I am not sure why it is behaving differently